# SQL Server stored procedure call using ODBC slow. (SQLExecDirect)

Tags: sql-server, performance, odbc

I have a C program making calls to a SQL Server stored procedure using `SQLExecDirect`.

The stored procedure itself does not do any SQL, just maps parameters and calls `sp_getapplock`. However performance of this is slow when run a number of times.

I have a 1000 loops of this, and using timings, see that 1 in every 20 takes about 15/16 milliseconds while other calls register barely any time at all. I've tried doing `SQLPrepare`, `SQLExecute`, changing drivers to Native etc, without difference. I even moved to SQL Server 2016 to try compiling stored procedure to native but can't as call to `sp_getapplock` won't compile.

I have commented out the `sp_getapplock` call itself in the stored procedure without a change in performance (in this case all it is doing is a few SETs) so I think issue must be on ODBC calling side.

- SQL Server 2016
- ODBC driver V13

Reference : [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-how-to/running-stored-procedures-call-stored-procedures)

Pseudo code:

```
static sql_handle = null;

if (sql_handle == null)
{
    SQLAllocStmt(..)

}

SQLBindParameter(..)
SQLBindParameter(..)

SQLExecDirect(handle, "{? = call MYSTOREDPROC(?,?)}");

SQLCancel();
```

Comment: Well the performance is going to suffer because you are calling the same procedure 1000 times in a loop. Data manipulation should be set based instead of running the same code over and over. It just doesn't work the same as application code.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2013** version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 in the works - so which one are you *really* using?

Comment: Version listed in Management studio is "SQL Server 13.0.1601.5" which apparently is 2016 . I am calling procedure with different parameters per iteraion and using sp_getapplock sp_releaselock . Strictly speaking there is plenty of C code externally within the loop, and the iterations is dependent on the client call . my question is that the stored procedure really only does a sp_getapplock / sp_releaselock, so where could time be getting lost?

Comment: Forgot to add that application and DB on same machine so no network latency involved and app is not intensive, Just difficult to understand what only 1 in 20 or so calls appear to be slow and rest are fine.